# Cannot add CloudTask to Azure Batch

Tags: c#, azure, azure-batch

I get an exception when try to add cloud task, width description "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.", at this line:

```
_job.AddTask(task);
```

of this method:

```
public static void AddTask(string taskId, string commandLine, IEnumerable<string> files)
        {
            var resourceFiles = files.Select(file => new ResourceFile(file, file)).Cast<IResourceFile>().ToList();
            var task = new CloudTask(taskId, commandLine) {ResourceFiles = resourceFiles};
            _job.AddTask(task);
        }
```

Comment: Useful link: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/batch-dotnet-get-started/

Comment: These tutorials, I was guided.

Answer (score 1):

Download the Azure Batch Explorer application, and connection your account to it. This will show you the running pools, work items, and jobs. The explorer will help you see if your job is running. Also, be sure each task you add has a unique name.

Answer (score 1):

How do you get the _job object? Does the job exist?

Try use WorkItemManager.GetJob() to get your job. Or use [Azure Batch Explorer](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Azure-Batch-Explorer-c1d37768) to make sure your workitem/job can be found and in Running state. (You can't add task to completed job.)